# Does Zend Translate auto detect language?

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation

This is my code

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);

$GLOBALS['translate'] = new Zend_Translate(
    array(
        'adapter' => 'array',
        'content' => array('Hello' => 'Hi'),
        'locale'  => 'en_US'
    )
);

gb('translate')->addTranslation(
    array(
        'content' => array('Hello' => 'Xin chào'),
        'locale' => 'vi'
    )
);

gb('translate')->_('Hello'); //always print Xin chào
```

It's always print 'Xin chào' even I use web proxy (from US) to request page.

Answer (score 4):

`Zend_Translate` is *locale aware*, which means it will use the `Zend_Locale` instance stored in the `Zend_Registry`:

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);
```

If you are not using the `Zend_Registry`, it will try to get the locale from the user's web browser (if available), information from the environment of the host server, and Zend Framework settings. To prevent this, you have to set the locale explicitly:

```
$translator->setLocale($locale);
```

See the chapter [Automatic Handling of Languages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.additional.html) in the reference guide for `Zend_Translate`